# In ElasticSearch should we use default_field in query String for nGram analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

i have created my index and mapping by this JSON

```
// 1st Mapping
    http://localhost:9200/hdm/entities/_mapping
    {
            "entities" : {
                "properties": {
                    "name": { "type": "string", "boost": 2.0, "analyzer": "snowball" },
                    "description": { "type": "string", "analyzer": "nGram" }
                }
            }
        }
// 2nd Mapping
    http://localhost:9200/hdm/products/_mapping
    {
        "products": {
            "_parent": { "type": "entities" },
            "properties": {
                "name": { "type": "string", "boost": 2.0, "analyzer": "snowball" },
                "code": { "type": "string", "analyzer": "snowball" },
                "segment": { "type": "string", "analyzer": "snowball" },
                "description": { "type": "string", "analyzer": "snowball" }
            }
        }
    }
```

now i have indexed some docs in this index using the JSON

```
    http://localhost:9200/hdm/entities/100
    {
        "name":"Entity 001",
        "description":"this is the company or an organization which provides the whole medicine, tablets injunction for the problem of human being those noting worth gaining was ever gained without effort

",
        "itype":"entities"
    }

    http://localhost:9200/hdm/products/101?parent=100
    {
        "name":"biorich",
        "description":"the tablet para is used to rectify the person from the all types of pain in the body, kingston , car, bat, ball, description of the products",
        "code":"COD19202",  
        "segment":"SEG1022",
        "itype":"products"
    }
```

for search i used this JSON

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "has_child": {
                "type": "products",
                "query": {
                  "query_string": {
                    "query": "tab"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "tablet"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "or": [
          {
            "term": {
              "itype": "entities"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i didn't get the result but i changed the query string like this then i got the result

```
      "query_string": {
        "default_field" : "description"
        "query": "tablet"
      }
```

could you please confirm me, should we mention the default_field in the querystring to get nGram analyzer result? my analyzer configuration is as follows

```
index.analysis.analyzer.mynGram.type: custom
index.analysis.analyzer.mynGram.tokenizer: standard
index.analysis.analyzer.mynGram.filter: [lowercase, mynGramFilter]
index.analysis.filter.mynGramFilter.type: nGram
index.analysis.filter.mynGramFilter.min_gram: 1
index.analysis.filter.mynGramFilter.max_gram: 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `"default_field"` is not specified in the query, elasticsearch is using special `_all` field to perform the search. Since you didn't change the default analyzer nor specified an analyzer for the `_all` field in your mapping, searches against the `_all` field are performed using [standard](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/standard-analyzer.html) analyzer.